# How to find singular solutions from a general one

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singular-solution

> Find singular solutions, if given general solution
>
> \begin{equation*} y= Ce^x + \dfrac{4}{C} \end{equation*}

Usually after solving the equation you will use the parameter for finding the singular solutions

$\left\{\begin{array}{l}F(x, y, p)=0 \\ \frac{\partial F(x, y, p)}{\partial p}=0\end{array}\right.$

I supposed that
$\left\{\begin{array}{l}y= Ce^x + \dfrac{4}{C}=0 \\ \frac{\partial F(x, y, C)}{\partial C}=e^x -\frac{4}{C^2}=0\end{array}\right.$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{equation*} y= Ce^x + \dfrac{4}{C} \end{equation*}$$
$y'=Ce^x$ then $C=\dfrac {y'}{e^x} \implies y= {y'}+\dfrac {4e^x} {y'}$

Now we have:
$$F(x,y,y')= {y'}+\dfrac {4e^x} {y'}-y=0$$
Differentiate with respect to $y'(y'=p)$ and solve:
$$\partial_{y'}F(x,y,y')= 1-\dfrac {4e^x} {y'^2}=0$$

Comment: Hi, I see you acknowledge the OP's formulation of the problem. Can you add information about how to find the singular solution given a general solution? Perhaps, formalize the idea a bit.  This type of problem is new to me and I find it interesting, thank you very much.

Comment: Hi just solve the last differential equation ....if you're new at this  then take a look here at the paragraph pDiscriminant  https://math24.net/singular-solutions-differential-equations.html  @A.P.